# Slow Encryption in Coldfusion

Tags: mysql, encryption, coldfusion

I have been trying to encrypt all the user's password in the MySql database using the following logic:

```
<cfquery datasource="mydatabase" name="userlist">
select userid, password
from mytable
LIMIT 0, 2000
</cfquery>

<cfoutput query="userlist">
<cfset pwd = encrypt(#userlist.password#, mykey, "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding", "hex")>
<cfquery datasource="mydatabase">
update members
set password = '#pwd#'
where userid = '#userid#'
</cfquery>
</cfoutput>
```

This seems simply enough just to encrypt 2000 records.  But the CF takes over 2 hours to do this!  It averages only encrypting 13 records in one minutes.  Is it something wrong with the code or is there a problem in CF Admin setting that needs to be tweak to speed up this thing?

p.s. the CF template does run but it will show 504 time-out on the browser in few minutes.  However, the 2000 records will still be completed in the background in 2 hours time.

**EDITED:**

I ran the first set of query on the database directly. It only took 0.05 seconds to retrieve all 2000 rows.  The second query to updated the database with already encrypted password took also less than a second.  That leaves only the CFOUTPUT query and the CFSET ENCRYPT lines that are causing the the 2.5 hours run.  I don't know how else to optimize this.

Comment: Off topic, and the reason it's just a comment. Are you familiar with hashing? There is no need to encrypt passwords in a decryptable format? Instead, you can hash the user's entered password each time they enter it (registration, login, matching for password-change). Among the several reasons hashing is preferred: Users typically insist on using ONE or as few as possible passwords everywhere. By providing their password in password-recovery (email "Your password is p@55word"), or over the phone, you may expose much of their online existence.

Comment: ...continued... I do not use mysql often but you can md5 hash on the database side, as shown here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844717/mysql-md5-select. Further, if you salt the hash (add your own string (like "sodium") to the hash that is not exposed anywhere, so long as it's the same salt for the user each time), you greatly increase the security as databases of straight hashes of entire dictionaries exist. Cookies md5's to `597b56e53847cd6a4712ac183f61fa68` but Cookiess (one more s) md5's to the very different `16fb9ddb550f238b848f8490854ef792`.

Comment: You could use the link I referenced above to hash into a new column and experiment for data integrity for your own ease. Something like `update table set hPwd = md5(password + 'Sodium' + username) where hPwd = '' limit(0, 2000)` so that you can still do it in pages if you like. There exist several hash functions, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html like SHA1

Comment: @cfqueryparam Thanks.  I would definitely use hash if not for the times that we may need to go into an account as a customer sees it, which means we need to know the password.

Comment: why are you involving CF in any of this? Can you not do your encryption (/hashing) directly within the DB?

Comment: @AdamCameron the whole site is running on CF.  That's why I haven't thought of using anything else.

Comment: Well there you go: you're thinking about it now. This is purely a data-processing exercise, so just use the data-processing tool at your disposal, ie: the DB.

Comment: Generally speaking, when changing the way one stores data, it's best to fix the future before fixing the past.  That way you only have to fix the past once.  That being the case, it shouldn't matter how long fixing the past takes because you only have to do it once.

Answer (score 1):

Working within comments was getting difficult..

In this post, I don't salt hashes, but it's just example stuff, you should definitely salt (add random, but consistent, string data).

Are you familiar with hashing? There is no need to encrypt passwords in a decryptable format. Instead, you can hash the user's entered password each time they enter it (registration, login, matching for password-change).

Among the several reasons hashing is preferred: Users typically insist on using ONE or as few as possible passwords everywhere. By providing their password in password-recovery (email "Your password is p@55word"), or over the phone, you may expose much of their online existence.

I do not use mysql often but you can md5 hash on the database side, as shown here, [MySQL MD5 SELECT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844717/mysql-md5-select). Further, if you salt the hash (add your own string (like "sodium") to the hash that is not exposed anywhere, so long as it's the same salt for the user each time), you greatly increase the security as databases of straight hashes of entire dictionaries exist. `Cookies` md5's to `597b56e53847cd6a4712ac183f61fa68` but `Cookiess` (one more s) md5's to the very different `16fb9ddb550f238b848f8490854ef792`.

You could use the link I referenced above to hash into a new column and experiment for data integrity for your own ease. Something like

```
update table
    set hPwd = md5(password + 'Sodium' + username)
  where hPwd = ''
  limit(0, 2000)
```

so that you can still do it in pages if you like. There exist several hash functions, see dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html like SHA1.

---

Jack replied

> Thanks. I would definitely use hash if not for the times that we may need to go into an account as a customer sees it, which means we need to know the password

Let me explain

When a user logs in, you would match their criteria like this

```
  select data_you_want
    from users_table
   where username = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#form.username#">
     and password = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#hash(form.password)#">
```

If that matches, you'd store the **hashed** password if you want to store the password in session data. Any pages where you want to re-affirm that the logged in user has the correct credentials, you'd use a query like this (notice the lack of hashing this time, vs the login query). Additionally you'd store asAdmin = 0, as a flag indicating that this is a normal user logging into their own account.

```
  select data_you_want
    from users_table
   where username = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#form.username#">
     and password = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#form.password#">
```

So, RE: wanting admins to be able to login. You create an admin gateway page that requires a different set of credentials (I'll get back to that) and if successful, you allow the user to login.

Because you want the user to still have some security, you might create a device like this... If a user is asking for admin assistance, you can give them a page to create an admin key like say `#randrange(1,1000000)#`

```
  <cfset akey = randrange(1,1000000)>
  ...
  update users_table
     set akey = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#akey#">
   where userID = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#session.userID#">
  ...

  You've requested some help from customer service and want them to login to your account.

  Please give them this key #decimalformat(akey)#.
  <!--- Decimal formatting makes the key easier to read, it's not stored that way --->
```

And then, when an admin logs in from a login page within the admin system, they enter the username and THIS KEY rather than a password.

That looks like this

```
  select data_you_want
    from users_table
   where username = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#form.username#">
     and akey = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#form.akey#">
```

If successful, it stores information similar to the login page that users normally access, no longer worries about the admin key.

Like

```
<cfscript>
AdminID = session.userID;
structclear(session); // get rid of all admin credentials, we're mimicing the user.
session.asAdmin = AdminID; // Create a flag that we can append to database activity if we want to track whether a user did this or an admin (and which admin!) did this on their behalf. If it's 0, it's the normal user, if it's greater than 0, it signifies which admin user did this.
session.username = GetUserStuffs.username;
session.pwd = GetUserStuffs.password; // because we're pulling a hashed password from the db, we do not rehash it.
session. ...other credentials you want in the session scope, the same things you'd store on normal user login...
</cfscript>

<!--- Now, use a client side redirect to send the admin, now logged in as the user, to the site root, or any normal-member-accessible-page. --->
<script>
  window.location = "/";
</script>
```

You can also reset the akey for the user on this page, so that the key is only good once.

Alternatively you can do this all without an akey but that allows your admins free roam of user accounts and that's grossly insecure.

Comment: thanks for this.  It would be great if I have an Admin system that mimic the user's system.  But it doesn't.  I have admin system that has all user profile and stuff they created.  But it will not help in the case say they are encountering system error in member's area.  The only true way to see the error in the member is encountering is by going in the same path as they login.  Hence the dilemma. :(

Comment: @Jack, the intent is to not duplicate the user's system, the intent is to use an admin gateway to actually inject the admin into the actual user system. If a user is experiencing an error anywhere but the login page, the admin would experience the error. Nothing is different. There is no reason that passwords need be exposed that trumps user security. I updated my post, but I show you how to clear the admin's session data and pick up exactly the same user data, with an additional flag which you may or may not want. If you don't use the flag, everything is identical.

Comment: This is way over my league.  My level of CF knowledge is more like high school vs your university level :)  Of course the problem now is I have already converted 14K members in these two days. 10 more days to go...so I am kind of stuck.  Now only if I can only get it running faster.

Comment: @Jack Thanks but apologies. I can understand being in "over your head" but trust me, there is never a good-enough reason not to be hashing passwords. Nobody but the users of the password should ever know the password. That trumps everything in this day and age. Because you are encrypting, you can decrypt and you can hash the decrypt. With that capability, please do your users/employers a favor and make hashed password storage a future goal.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong.  If the DB ever get compromised, I think it would be more difficult to break the password that is encrypted vs hashed, isn't it?

Comment: @Jack Nope, Hashed passwords can't be unhashed. The only way to find the proper input string is to keep trying strings. There is only hash collisions, where two values hash to the same string but there is a 1/18,446,744,073,709,551,616 (for md5). The chance of this is well... it's just phenomenally small. Further, while my example uses md5 hashing, it's only because it's the default of the hash function. You can use a number of algorithms with CF's hash function. Salted Hashing is the superior choice.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue may be because of having lots of individual cfquery calls when you execute the code so it's not very efficient. In the past I've tackled this by just using ColdFusion to create and render the SQL in your browser. You can then take that output and run it directly against the database which should be quicker to execute.

So your code would be something like this:

```
<cfquery datasource="mydatabase" name="userlist">
    select userid, password
    from mytable
    LIMIT 0, 2000
</cfquery>

<cfoutput>
<pre>
<cfloop query="userlist">
    <cfset pwd = encrypt(userlist.password, mykey, "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding", "hex")>
    SET @pwd = '#pwd#';
    SET @userid = #userlist.userid#;

    UPDATE members
    SET password = @pwd
    WHERE userid = @userid;
</cfloop>
</pre>
</cfoutput>
```

This will produce an output something like this:

```
SET @pwd = '0E8C9C1026C0EB950CA8A398C8E5ED6B';
SET @userid = 1;

UPDATE members
SET password = @pwd
WHERE userid = @userid;

SET @pwd = 'F6B9CE35A39A15D791F7C3711399493A';
SET @userid = 2;

UPDATE members
SET password = @pwd
WHERE userid = @userid;

SET @pwd = '1DB3AA5B3DF622CE905BD4E992B24E6D';
SET @userid = 3;

UPDATE members
SET password = @pwd
WHERE userid = @userid;
```

You can then run those SQL statements directly against the database server.

Ideally you should be using one-way encryption, but that's another question which is detailed here: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords

Comment: (Ignoring the encrypt vs hash argument for a moment) Why not just move the loop inside the cfquery? Then you could generate multiple sql statements, and still use cfqueryparam. Bind variables are designed for exactly this situation ie executing the same SQL statement multiple times. (SQL Injection protection is just an added benefit). Having said all that, @Jack *passwords should be hashed*, not encrypted.

Comment: Hi John, I ran your way but it still took over 2 hours to generate the list.  The running of the list took a second.  But preparing that list is frustrating.  @Leigh I am not sure what you mean the loop inside the cfquery?  I would definitely use hash if not for from time to time that we need to actually sign in as a member sees it to find the error they are encountering.

Comment: @leigh Good points and in reply: because the original question was about the speed the script executes. By running the SQL directly against MySQL you remove any speed issues with ColdFusion. Also looping inside cfquery with 1,000s of records can have it's own problems http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7128852/is-there-a-limit-on-how-long-a-cfquery-with-cfqueryparam-can-get

Comment: @Jack - it should not take anywhere near that long! I just did 2000 in under a second: `<cfscript>
  i = 0;
  while (i < 2000) {
   encrypt("hello", generateSecretKey("AES"), "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding", "hex");
    i++;
  }
</cfscript>`

Comment: @JohnWhish - I was not suggesting running *all* 2K statements in a single query. That is a bit much IMO ;-) While I agree with your assessment that reducing the overall number of db queries will help performance, this type of job is best broken into batches IMO. Strike a healthy balance in between all or nothing. Run a batch of `x` statements until finished. However, that should be done with cfqueryparam, rather than string literals. Since you're executing the same sql statement, over and over, bind variables will help the db reuse the execution plan, reducing the overall execution time.

Comment: @Leigh yeah I know what you're saying & agree that you should use bindings, I would generated the SQL to use variables like `update members set password = @password where userid = @userid`. I was just trying to not get too far off topic and focus on taking ColdFusion out of the equation as that seemed to be where the performance issue was, maybe I should write longer answers :)

Comment: @JohnWhish you lost me there.  Can you maybe update your answer so that I can relate? :-)  Oh BTW, 2000 is already broken down!  I have over 100K to run.  Doing like this I will be running all week!  I have started the process yesterday and only got 10K done.  :-(

Comment: @JohnWhish - Haha. Normally I would not mention it. I only did here because performance was part of the issue - and this is exactly the type of query that benefits (performance wise) from cfqueryparam. Jack - As John said, this query should not be taking so long. Is your table indexed on `userID`? Did you time the code? How long is each step taking? *we need to actually sign in as a member* If you really need to do that, there are better ways to build in an impersonation feature, while still using hash. See cfqueryparam's answer for one option.

Comment: @Leigh Userid is indexed.  I don't know what you mean time the code?  I run the template and it will get a 504 time-out error.  I asked the tech to increase apach time out and I am getting "Could not connect to JRun Server." error. However, the "job" will still get done.  I see on Mysql admin that records are being encrypted one by one in the database but slowly.

Comment: I meant when you're planning a big task, you don't just run the code. You break it down into steps. Then test and time the individual pieces (ie one encrypt call, one db update, etc..) to get an estimate of how long the overall task will take. *RE: I see on Mysql admin that records are being encrypted* Hm... did you try and run the template multiple times? If so, do you have any code in place that will prevent the values from being encrypted twice? :/

Comment: I have been changing the LIMIT clause.  When 2000 are done, I increment it.  And it takes about 2 hours each.  At this rate, it's going to take me whole week to convert.

Comment: That wouldn't prevent the same records from being double or triple encrypted if you attempted to re-run the script multiple times. Did you? Do you have a backup of the database? At this point, you might want to kill the script, restore the db, and start over again with a more solid plan. Though I'd strongly recommend getting assistance from someone familiar w/MySQL so as not to exacerbate the problem.

Comment: I change the LIMIT clause which will only select the next 2000 record and encrypt them one by one.  I checked it every time so it won't encrypt over already encrypted password.  But I just can't figure out why it's so slow.  Maybe a CF Admin memory setting or something I am missing.

Comment: @JohnWhish the new code that you have edited made it worst.  The list still took 2.5 hours to generate and putting the output against the DB crashed/timout my table.  Definitely worst than the original suggestion.

Comment: @Jack interesting... I did have a thought about this, have you tried upgrading your JVM? You haven't mentioned which version of CF / JVM you are on. Maybe there is a bug in the JVM you have so upgrading may solve the issue. Also have you tried a test run on a different server - if so is it as slow?

Comment: @JohnWhish I am using CF9.  Minimum JVM Heap Size 512 and Maximum is 768. Also -XX:MaxPermSize=192m.  Java VM Version 14.0-b16.  I don't have another server to try this.

Comment: @Jack I definitely try upgrading the JVM to the latest 1.6 - it's quite easy to do and you can switch it back again (if you don't overwrite the files). Details here: http://www.carehart.org/blog/client/index.cfm/2011/10/28/cf911-have-you-updated-your-coldfusion-jvm-to-24-yet-important-security-fix-for-cf-89 and instructions are here: http://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/change-jvm-coldfusion-jrun.html.